# Replacing String Columnwise Using Sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed, replace

Given this data

```
34 foo
34 bar
34 qux
62 foo1
62 qux
78 qux
```

I want to replace the string at 2nd column into "" if it is "qux".
Resulting:

```
34 foo
34 bar
34 
62 foo1
62 
78
```

How do you do that with sed? In particular the data is very big with ~10^7 lines

Comment: Hey, is it space delimited, or whitespace delimited (spaces+tabs)?

Comment: Well, POSIX sed can't use '\t' to match tabs; you have to use literal tabs. gsed can, but awk will definitely match tabs with \t

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I *wouldn't* actually do it with `sed` since that's not the best tool for the job. The `awk` tool is my tool of choice whenever somebody mentions columns.

```
cat file | awk '$2 == "qux" { print $1 } $2 != "qux" { print $0 }'
```

or the simplest form:

```
cat file | awk '{ if ($2 == "qux") {$2 = ""}; print }'
```

If you must use `sed`:

```
cat file | sed 's/  *qux *$//'
```

making sure that you use the correct white space (the above uses only spaces).

Comment: @Pax: thanks for the reply. BUt yours approach with awk give this instead: 
34 bar
34
34 qux
62 foo1
62
62 qux
78
78 qux

Comment: Try again. I had a $s instead of $2.

Answer (score 3):

No trailing spaces:

```
sed 's/qux$//' < file
```

If it must be in the second column (of potentially more than three columns):

```
sed 's/\([0-9][  ]*\)qux\(.*\)/\1\2/'
```

(Note that there is a literal tab and space; sed doesn't match tabs with '\t';

But awk is better for tabular data:

```
awk '{ if ($2 == "qux") {$2 = ""; print} else { print }; }' < file
```

Comment: If you want to keep the blank lines sed 's/qux//' < file

Comment: That awk solution doesn't change the file (in Cygwin at least).

Comment: Never mind, I see the problem, it was the second ==, I've fixed it for ya'.

Comment: @Pax: if I want to do in-place replacement to the file how could I do it?  And in AWK how do you print with tab delimited? Now it prints with space delimited.

Comment: @foolishbrat sed and awk don't do in place edits; you can use perl for that, or super sed (ssed). Otherwise the standard thing to do is use a temporary file.

Comment: @foolishbrat, you could pass the output through <sed 's/SPACE/TAB/g'> - that's the fastest way to get a result.

Comment: Or there's an OFS variable which is by default a space - set that to a tab. But you shouldn't need to, since $0 preserves the tabs (in my answer - I haven't tested guns').

Answer (score 1):

```
 nawk '{ gsub( /qux/, " " ); print }' filename
```